# How to connect MySQL database to C# WinForm Application?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

How do you connect a MySQL database to a C# WinForm Application?

I can establish a connection using a Microsoft SQL Server, but cannot for the life of me figured out how it's done using MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
string myConnectionString = "server=localhost;database=testDB;uid=root;pwd=abc123;";
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open!");
        cnn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot open connection!");
    }
}
```

Make sure that you have a proper reference in your code:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

And this connection string is just an example. You have to see what is your connection string ofc. And also search for these kind of questions because I'm sure that there is a bunch of similar or even the same questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need MySQL Connector / Net .  Install this, then you'll get a suite of classes like MySqlConnection, MySQLCommand, MySQLDataReader, etc.

These are analogous to SqlConnection and similar classes for MS Sql Server.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
new class conection.cs use this code:

```html
class Conection
    {       
        public static string ConectionString = "server=localhost;database=testDB;uid=root;pwd=abc123;";           
    }
```

**Step 2**
Add namespace to the project:

```html
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

**Step 3**
Create a MySQL connection string:

```html
String ConectionString = infor.ConectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
```

**Step 4**
The following code will insert the data into MySQL table:

```html
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open!");
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot open connection!");
    }
}
```

**NOTE!** this connection string is just an example.